# Theme problems with vim and terminal

Tags: bash, vim, plugins

everyone.   Trying to figure out a weird problem I'm having with VIM, that's probably just me being a complete novice with the program.

I started using it today, and was told to use Vundle to manage plugins, which is fine.  I've instead got a problem with one of the plugins I'm using, as well as general color scheme issues.

I'm running the latest release of Linux Mint, and have a .bashrc that contains simply one line:

`TERM=xterm-256color`

Anyway, I am using the Luna color scheme for VIM, located at https://github.com/Pychimp/vim-luna, as well as the same-named theme for the `vim-airline` plugin.

When I load up VIM, it looks completely wrong.  Not sure what's going on, but I really want to get it fixed.  The screenshot below is how it looks when I load up a file or something:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbAmz.jpg

Anyway, if anyone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong, or what I have misconfigured...I'd really appreciate it.   The contents of my `.vimrc` are as follows:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
set number
syntax on
colorscheme luna
filetype off                  " required

let g:airline_theme='base16'
let g:airline_powerlinei_fonts = 1
set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript' 
Plugin 'othree/javascript-libraries-syntax.vim' 
Plugin 'ap/vim-css-color'
Plugin 'elzr/vim-json'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'marijnh/tern_for_vim'


" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line

autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTreeType") && b:NERDTreeType == "primary") | q | endif
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Comment: First day in Vim and you already waste your time with pointless plugins? I'd suggest removing everything from your vimrc except lines 2, 3, 9, 31 and learning Vim instead.

Comment: I've used vim before in the past.  I was using the wrong theme file (one was for gvim, one for terminal).  I just hadn't used it in a while.  I guess i miswrote that.  Anyway, yeah.